# Spark 2.x saveAsTable

Tags: hive, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to use the Spark 2.1.0 java api to persist a DataFrame (Dataset of rows) as a Hive table. I tried using the `saveAsTable` method in the `DataFrameWriter` class.

My code looks like: `df.write(appendMode).saveAsTable("tablename");`

I get an `AnalysisException` stating that

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:saving data in my Hive serde
>   table is not supported yet. Please use the `insertInto()` API as an
>   alternative

Can I really not use the `saveAsTable` method? It isn't marked as deprecated in the api documentation.

Comment: does your table already exist?

Comment: yes. I am trying to append to a pre-existing table

Comment: what is your table format? does it solve your issue specify the format during the save? for example, if it is parquet 

df.write(appendMode).format("parquet"). saveAsTable("tablename");

Comment: Specifying the table format does not solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

The exception is because, the table"tablename" in which you are trying to append data is created with the `"Hive serde"`, that means, the data inside the table `tablename` will be stored as text file.

As, you are using the `saveAsTable` Api, which writes the data in `parquet` format using the `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe` serde. So the spark api, can not append parquet data with text, that's why the exception is.

Solution: Do not create the table beforehand, Let the "`saveAsTable`" Api create the table itself with the schema of data frame and properties it need for the first time and then it keeps appending the data in it.

If at all you need to create the table yourself, you need to make sure the table is stored as parquet and with appropriate `TBLPROPERTIES` . e.g is below:

```
    CREATE TABLE `savetest`(
  `channel` string,
  `address` string,
  `curr_date` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false',
  'numFiles'='2',
  'numRows'='-1',
  'rawDataSize'='-1',
  'spark.sql.sources.provider'='parquet',
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1',
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"channel\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"address\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"curr_date\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}'
  )
```